# Java Mongodb client

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee

I need to set a mongodb client in my J2EE code, the returned is a void, even it has to print out the name of collections. I can not debug my code, it seems correct, is it a problem with the driver ?

Please find here the code :

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;


import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet (name="Faces Servlet",urlPatterns={"/faces/*"})
public class TestCon extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter();
        writer.println("Hello World !!!");
    }

    public static void main(String args) throws Exception {
        MongoClient mongoClient;
        DB db;

        mongoClient = new MongoClient( "192.168.1.254" , 27017 );

        db = mongoClient.getDB( "syslog" );             
        Set<String> tables = db.getCollectionNames();
        for(String coll : tables) {
            System.out.println(coll);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your `main()` method works fine as a standalone application on my system. Provided that the host and database names are correct, it should output all user and system collection names in that database.

As your whole *servlet* code stands, however, that method does not appear to be callable by your servlet container. Your `doGet()` method is a plain-old *"Hello World!!!"*, with no calls to MongoDB-related code. There is no call to `main()` in your `doGet()` method, the design implications of calling `main()` from an instance method notwithstanding.

Furthermore, you are using `System.out.*()` for output, which may not work as expected within the environment of an application server - in most (all?) cases it would send the message to the server log, if at all.

How exactly are you using this code? As a standalone application, or as a servlet? Are there any related error messages in your servlet container logs?

Comment: "There is no call to the `main()` from the `doGet()`"? Seriosly ?

Comment: @kocko: it is a valid observation. As it is, the code called by the application server is just a "Hello world!". The MongoDB code lies in a part of the class that is not used by the servlet code. The OP may be just confused on how servlets work, but unless they tell us how they are using this code, there is not much more to say...

Comment: I guess you know what the `main()` method is about. You should've said that he should place his code in the `init()` method of the Servlet, for example, if he wants to (re)use the MongoDB connection in the `doGet()`

Comment: @kocko: I think that the OP has more basic issues than reusing a MongoDB connection :-)